# How do I get middle x and y coordinates for a view xcode objective-c

Tags: objective-c, xcode

So i have been trying to get a button on the top of the screen that moves a cannon to the top of the screen and then a button on the bottom of the screen that moves it to the bottom of the screen but my code isn't working so far. Here is what i have for the top button.

```
CGRect frame = cannon.frame; 
frame.origin.x = CGRectGetMidX(view.frame);
frame.origin.y = CGRectGetMinY(view.frame);

[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:5.0];
cannon.frame = frame;
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your Question you need the center of a view...

The easiest would be to use:

```
 CGPoint centerPoint = view.center;
```

Yet in your code I am seeing:

```
 frame.origin.y = CGRectGetMinY(view.frame);
```

Which I believe should be (note Mid instead of Min):

```
 frame.origin.y = CGRectGetMidY(view.frame);
```